# TNS:protocol adapter error Oracle 11g R2 Express Edition

Tags: oracle

ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
Windows could not start the OracleServiceXE service on Local Computer.
Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Comment: What version of Windows? Has it ever worked or has anything changed recently? Is there any anti-virus software running?

Comment: And please note that 11g went out of support in Dec 2020.

Comment: Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: Initially it was working fine, de to a special character in password, it stopped working whn I tried to login to DB the next so I had to reinstall it and after reinstallation I am geting this error now.

Comment: Since you are re-installing anyway, I'd download 21c Express Edition and go with that. Lots more features and still free.